# Issue selecting armature bones blender 2.92

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I am having issues with selecting bones for weight painting. In **object mode**, i select **armature and then the mesh**, then go to **weight painting**. I have tried shift+click and also ctrl+click on another bone but the selection wont move from the selected thigh bone we see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: This does not sound like how weight painting works. Please check the documentation at docs.blender.org